# Laravel Multiple Middleware in Route with OR Condition

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, boolean, middleware

I wonder if I can do this in Laravel Route. Let's say I have `Admin`, `Premium` and `User` (which can be login too by using `Auth`) Middleware. Also, I have controller with methods like this: `index`, `create`, `edit`, `delete` and I want `Admin` to be able do all those things, but `Premium` can only be able to access `index` method, and `User` can't access anything in this controller (he can access another controller). I know I can use `except` or `only` middleware method like this:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('premium')->only('index');
        $this->middleware('admin'); 
        // or maybe $this->middleware('admin')->except('index');
    }
```

but when I try to put these two middlewares in `__construct` method they will start to conflict each other, it makes sense because index method can be access by `Premium` but then can't be access by the `Admin` itself. By the way, my middleware is simply checking:

```
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'Admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/home');
```

So, back to my question, can I have OR Middleware so I can avoid conflict from multiple middleware (which is must be AND condition when they written at the same controller constructor)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change up the way your logic is thinking a little bit, the answer becomes pretty easy. You can create new middleware that checks if it can access the specific method.

So create the following middleware 'CanAccessIndex':

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    if (Auth::user()->role == 'Admin' || Auth::user()->role == 'Premium') {
        return $next($request);
    }
 }
return redirect('/home');
```

Then, you can put that middleware on the index function (instead of the premium middleware) and put your admin middleware on everything EXCEPT index. Like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('canAccessIndex')->only('index');
    $this->middleware('admin')->except('index');
}
```

That's one way to do it.

Comment: thanks for your advice.. I once do think like your answer but I'm afraid to change my middleware as they can get so messy when you do wrong logic..

Answer (score 5):

You need middleware group for this, and to manage these hierarchy of access layer, you can simply use *Route grouping*.

I will demo an example of what I mean:
Say you have `auth` middleware general for authenticated users (i.e everybody), then another called `premium` for premium member, and `admin` for the Admin.

Then you'll group based on the access level:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware('premium')->group(function(){
        Route::post('/create', 'HomeController@create')->middleware('admin');
        Route::put('/update/{id}', 'HomeController@update')->middleware('admin');
        Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::put('/delete/{id}', 'HomeController@delete')->middleware('admin');
    });
});
```

So you can have general check in your middleware with a check. It would have been much easier if you have role level say 3 for admin and 2 for premium member. So we can have for the premium middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return auth()->user->role >= 2
        ? $next($request)
        : redirect('/home');
}
```

This is just an example. You can do further check based on your need but more importantly, ensure your `admin` middleware to checks the exact role level that is allowed.